# Heroku not recognizing existing column in ActiveRecord schema/database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I'm new to Rails so please let me know if I leave out any important info. Trying to create a simple flashcard app using two AR tables:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150709042557) do

create_table "cards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "word_text",    null: false
    t.string  "meaning_text", null: false
    t.integer "user_id",      null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "card_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end
end
```

The word_text column is the word on the card, meaning_text is the other side.

Works fine in rails console and on local server but when I push to heroku I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `word_text' for nil:NilClass):
22:
23: <br> <br> <%= button_tag(type: 'button') do %>
24:
25: <h1 style="color:yellow"> <%= @card.word_text %>
26:
27: <ul><%= link_to 'Tap to flip card', card_path(@card) %></ul>
```

After googling, I attempted to create card objects using `heroku run console` when I discovered:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):002:0> c = Card.new
=> #<Card id: nil, word_id: nil, meaning_id: nil>
```

Am I missing something, or is this the reason why Heroku is not recognizing word_text and meaning_text and why I am unable to create these objects (despite them being present in my development database?)

I've run multiple migrations, double checked that I seeded my db correctly and am able to run the app successfully locally. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You just need data.  `Card.new` won't persist a new instance.  Try `Card.create` with desired attributes.  Or you can use a seed file to populate your database (a better approach if you have a fixed set of data you want to populate since it is repeatable this way and can be automated).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... forgot to mention i tried doing this, using data from my seed file and dropping it in heroku console, but got pretty much the same error:    

`irb(main):001:0> Card.create(word_text: "el perro", meaning_text: "the dog", user_id: 1)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'word_text' for Card.`

Comment: `reload!` in console or restart console?  Your migration looks OK, so your console (and possibly server) need to be reloaded or restarted.  You can also enter `Card` in your console to see if you and Rails agree on the schema for this model.

Comment: try `heroku run rake db:reset` if you don't care for any data in the database, then `heroku restart`

Comment: just tried  `heroku restart -a <app>`   and re-opening, and then also tried reload! in the console but neither of these worked... 

Entered Card to see and it was this: 
1irb(main):003:0> Card
=> Card(id: integer, word_id: integer, meaning_id: integer)`

Comment: `heroku run rake db:reset` did it, it works now.. thanks!

Comment: I have this problem, but I can't reset my DB, what to do?